# Inverse geospatial search with Lucene

Tags: lucene, geospatial

Is there a way to implement something like "inverse" geospatial search with Lucene? With inverse I mean, the indexed objects each define both a position (lat/lng) and a radius. I want to find all objects where my search position is within the radius of the indexed objects.

A real life example could be a set of pizza delivery services, each of them delivers an area of radius x. I want to find all pizza services that could deliver a pizza to me. So, it is not me defining the search radius, it is defined by the target objects.

All I have found yet implements a search within a given radius.
Any links/hints even to different technologies are welcome.