# Bidirectional geospatial search

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

**The Setup**

- I have two models in my application: Viewers and Posts
- Both viewers and posts have

  - A location specified by lat/lon fields
  - A radius represented by an integer value

**The requested behaviour**

- Viewers may only see posts which are within their current search radius
- Viewers may only see posts if they are within the post's radius. This is to provide a field of visibility for posts.

Basically, the following rules have to apply for a post to be displayed:

```ruby
post.radius   >= distance(post, viewer)
viewer.radius >= distance(post, viewer)
```

**The problem**

The first rule is not too difficult to implement:

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    integer :radius
    latlon(:location) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(latitude, longitude) }
  end
end

# PostController
Post.search do
  with(:location).in_radius(viewer.latitude, viewer.longitude, viewer.radius)
end
```

The second rule, however, would require that I am able to utilize the distance between the post and the viewer inside the solr query, e.g. with

```ruby
with(:radius).greater_than distance(:location, viewer.latitude, viewer.longitude)
```

As far as I see it, there is no way to achieve this with sunspot's built in methods. 
Is solr even capable of handling queries like this?

If not, what might be a better solution to handle this problem?

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623808/inverse-geospatial-search-with-lucene) question seems to go into the same direction, but is a little more vague and not directly related to sunspot.

**Edit**:

Motivation: My current solution is to only fetch posts which satisfy the first rule (are in the viewer's radius) and filter out posts with a radius `< distance(viewer, post)` afterwards. 
This is now done using Sunspot's hits instead of results (see comments) to remove unwanted posts from the resulting database query.

This solution works, but it messes up Solr's total result count and pagination. In the worst case, the whole current page might be empty (all posts were filtered out). Therefore, it would be best if both rules would be applied within the query (within Solr).

Comment: You can run 2 separate queries and get the intersection of their results, but I guess you want to do both in `Post.search`.

Comment: Exactly. Filtering the results outside of `Post.search` would be a solution, but it would also slow down the whole query a lot

Comment: Your 2 rules can be merged: `distance(post, viewer) <= min(viewer.radius, post.radius)`. So if you can somehow reference the post radius in the restriction, like `with(:location).in_radius(viewer.latitude, viewer.longitude, min(:radius, viewer.radius))`, you're golden.

Comment: That would indeed simplify the query, but as you said, the main problem is referencing the radius. Without this, neither the naive nor the merged rules will work.

Comment: Another possible workaround: [store](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#highlighting) the post radius, run your first rule, then [loop through your hits](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Working-with-search#getting-search-results) and keep only posts where radius <= viewer.radius.

Comment: see this page http://de.slideshare.net/LucidImagination/spatial-search-with-geohashes, perhaps helps you.

Comment: @user880772: Good idea, I'm currently looping over the fetched posts. This will at least result in a smaller database query.

Comment: @Samane As far as I understand it, the geohash solution is not very effective if I need POIs within an exact radius. Otherwise, it's a very interesting concept.